# Angular 2/4 Cannot read property 'next' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I have a service  as common.shared.service.ts

```
import { AuthService } from '../../services/api/auth-service';
import { Observable, Observer, Subject } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class CommonSharedService {

data: any;
dataChange: Observable<any>;
private dataChangeObserverl ;

 constructor() {
  this.dataChange = new Observable(observer =>
  this.dataChangeObserverl = observer).share();
 }

 setData(data: any) {
  this.data = data;
  this.dataChangeObserverl.next(this.data);
 }
}
```

Now i set Data when i return a promise  in my one of teh component like here in HeaderComponent

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

 user: {};
 constructor(private authService: AuthService, private 
   commonSharedService: CommonSharedService) {};

 ngOnInit() {

 this.authService.get()
 .subscribe(
  (response) => {
    this.user = response;
    this.commonSharedService.setData(response);
   } ,
   (error) => {
    console.log(error)
   }
  }
 }
```

But when i get the suth user Object in some other compoenent then it give error

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'next' of undefined. I think that because i set the value after returning promise thats why some times it giving this error how to resolve this. Kindly Help.

In Some Other Component

```
this.commonSharedService.dataChange.subscribe((data) => {
    console.log(data);})
}
```

Comment: You con not give `response` as Observer

Comment: have you tried sth like this: `let a = this.authService.get(); this.sharedService.setData(a); a.subscribe( (response) => ..do whatever )`

Comment: It seems you should use a Subject rather than hacking an Observable the way you're doing in your service. The observer will be undefined until someone subscribes to the observable.

Comment: @JB Nizet Can you elaborate how to solve

Comment: By replacing your dataChange Observable by a Subject, and by calling the Subject's next() method when setting the data.

Comment: if i subscribe and get the data in one component will that be available in another component if i subscribe again..

Comment: basically what i want it a shared service to store auth user object